# Everything in Firestore is working except when the document doesn't exist

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class OrderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  String companyId;
  OrderWidget(this.companyId);
  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getData() async*{
    var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('companies').doc(companyId).collection('orders').doc(user.uid).snapshots();
    }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: getData(),
      builder: (ctx, snapshots){
      if(snapshots.hasData){
================================================here is the problem========================
           return Column(children: [
            SizedBox(height: 70,), 
              Container(
                        height: 350,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 5,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('OrderID:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                                        Text(snapshots.data['orderId'], style: TextStyle(fontSize:18),),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Service:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                                        Text(snapshots.data['partName'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                   Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Old price:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                                        Text(snapshots.data['oldPrice'], style:TextStyle(fontSize:18),),
                                      ],),
                                  ),
                                   Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Price:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                                        Text(snapshots.data['price'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Discount:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                                        Text(snapshots.data['discount'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                                          child: FlatButton(
                                            onPressed: (){
                                              snapshots.data.reference.delete();
                                              
                                            }, 
                                            child: Text('Remove'),
                                            color: Colors.red,
                                            textColor: Colors.white,
                                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                                            ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
          ]
            );
         }else{
           if(snapshots.hasError){
            return Center(child: Text('There is no Orders yet!'),);}
         }
      }
      );
  }
}
```

Here is the error in console:

```
The following StateError was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>>#4c964):
Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist
The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>
package:iparts_user/widgets/orders_widget.dart:18
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get
package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/…/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:76
#1      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.get
package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:92
#2      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.[]
package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:96
#3      OrderWidget.build.<anonymous closure>
package:iparts_user/widgets/orders_widget.dart:39
#4      StreamBuilder.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/async.dart:545
...
```

Comment: Did you try doing a direct `snapshots.data != null` if else clause ?

Comment: Yes i did but it didn't work, it just shows it for a 2 seconds then it shows the red screen with a bad state

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following StateError was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>>#4c964):
Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist

Comment: When the document of the user exists in firestore everything work as required but when the document doesn't exist it shows this error

Comment: On which line is this error coming. Add you full error to the question.

Comment: i just added the error to the question you can check it out

Comment: Solved it out with 
    if(snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
    if(!snapshots.data.exists)
    if(snapshots.hasData)

Answer (score 0):

The error is in how you're reading the information from the DocumentSnapshot.

This line below:

```dart
snapshots.data['orderId']
```

should be updated to:

```dart
snapshots.data.data()['orderId']
```

> DocumentSnapshotPlatform class Contains data read from a document in
> your Firestore database.
>
> The data can be extracted by calling data() or by calling get() to get
> a specific field.
>
> [DocumentSnapshotPlatform class](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/DocumentSnapshotPlatform-class.html)

Comment: it didn't work... gave a line of error code

Comment: the issue here my friend, if collection('orders').doc(user.uid) exists in firestore everything works but if it doesn't exists it returns an error which is the red screen with a bad state. so rather than returning the bad state error i need to return in a text that there is no orders yet,

Comment: Solved it out with 
    if(snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
    if(!snapshots.data.exists)
    if(snapshots.hasData)